# Field authenticationManager in *** required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("SampleClientId")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info")
                .autoApprove(true) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

and following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.2.RELEASE'    
}
```

When I start application I see following log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=50479 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50480:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\work\sso\server\out\production\classes;D:\work\sso\server\out\production\resources;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.1.RELEASE\88751ed76791d12425ce5a80476baf1749a44cf4\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security.oauth\spring-security-oauth2\2.3.2.RELEASE\cf6e03591f593139f1d1d44278d962090aa226c9\spring-security-oauth2-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.1.RELEASE\f2e1aeeb1ac02bfa1b4f7254633484af1866fc65\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.1.RELEASE\33abc1286b0aabea4f08ff4285d09e587835a716\spring-boot-starter-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.0.1.RELEASE\4b46f4aaff6c8a5a1c8184996d5e9e8a9354db8d\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.9.Final\b149e4cce82379f11f6129eb3187ca8ae5404005\hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.5.RELEASE\a7fd53c7ad06b0fa7dd4ff347de1b2dc508739e\spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-web\5.0.4.RELEASE\bd2592c928d043f70742fd8ae409f751a63132dd\spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.0.5.RELEASE\d51dbb5cabe72ae02e400577bac48f7fc94088de\spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-config\5.0.4.RELEASE\355fc8c3d1c61fe85915082587946ad346250d85\spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-core\5.0.4.RELEASE\f2924cd62fa8b14546b2b3c31dcd9e55abf9a5e\spring-security-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.1.RELEASE\b0bf9d34ed70c6987a86cd58a009065e5fa02545\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.0.1.RELEASE\b8c5b14cbb0e52fdded8f98a8c1493cc74c7cf59\spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.0.5.RELEASE\9cca4bf5acb693249a01c218f471c677b951d6e2\spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.0.5.RELEASE\b11b61b94d7fb752a1c9bf3461d655c3084fae47\spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.0.5.RELEASE\984445863c0bbdaaf860615762d998b471a6bf92\spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.0.5.RELEASE\fc6c7a95aeb7d00f4c65c338b08d97767eb0dd99\spring-expression-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.0.5.RELEASE\1bd9feb1d9dac6accd27f5244b6c47cfcb55045c\spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.11\3acb4705652e16236558f0f4f2192cc33c3bd189\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\1ee2f2bed0e5dd29d1cb155a166e6f8d50bbddb7\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.1.RELEASE\10681a28c95e9f9c0159327a1ed0c860517c7ad7\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\2d998d3d674b172a588e54ab619854d073f555b5\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.5\23e37f085279ba316c0df923513b81609e1d1f6\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.5\d1f0d11e816bc04e222a261106ca138801841c2d\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.5\f824c60751ffb7bfc3a0d30dfe0e42317d8e67f5\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.9.5\3490508379d065fe3fcb80042b62f630f7588606\jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.29\37786f4ca8a1597a91a0f437e659a76d1fcc5bf1\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.29\51eac5adde4bc019261b787cb99e5548206908e6\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.29\893fb2c87ec1aa248a7911d76c0c06b3fca6bc9b\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.29.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\3d5f48f10bbe4eb7bd862f10c0583be2e0053c6\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.5.RELEASE\f4a2854b9d865e8b86717595aec16f877f8c6489\spring-jcl-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\3c304d70f42f832e0a86d45bd437f692129299a4\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\f7e631ccf49cfc0aefa4a2a728da7d374c05bd3c\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\af5364cd6679bfffb114f0dec8a157aaa283b76\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.9.5\a22ac51016944b06fd9ffbc9541c6e7ce5eea117\jackson-core-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ntkachev\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\fec5797a55b786184a537abd39c3fa1449d752d6\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar" com.my.sso.server.AuthorizationServerApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-04-12 18:07:40.163  INFO 1252 --- [           main] c.m.s.s.AuthorizationServerApplication   : Starting AuthorizationServerApplication on ntkachev with PID 1252 (D:\work\sso\server\out\production\classes started by ntkachev in D:\work\sso\server)
2018-04-12 18:07:40.166  INFO 1252 --- [           main] c.m.s.s.AuthorizationServerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-12 18:07:40.204  INFO 1252 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@8e0379d: startup date [Thu Apr 12 18:07:40 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-12 18:07:41.040  INFO 1252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2018-04-12 18:07:41.060  INFO 1252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.061  INFO 1252 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-04-12 18:07:41.064  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-2.3-all\gradle-2.3\bin;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Users\ntkachev\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ntkachev\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Python27;D:\work\fiddler;.]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.138  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-12 18:07:41.138  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 936 ms
2018-04-12 18:07:41.237  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.237  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.237  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.237  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.237  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.237  INFO 1252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.268  WARN 1252 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2018-04-12 18:07:41.285  INFO 1252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-12 18:07:41.292  INFO 1252 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-12 18:07:41.355 ERROR 1252 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field authenticationManager in com.my.sso.server.AuthServerConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What wrong with my configuration?

Actually I try to repeat ecxample from http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2 and I don't see explicit declaration of this bean

Answer (score 7):

Need to add

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
@Configuration
public class UserSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. How can I set it up?

Answer (score 4):

Seems that I've found the solution to the issue, besides that we need add spring-boot-starter-security dependency, starting from spring-security 5.x bean of type AuthenticationManager is not autoconfigured for you, you need to define one by yourself
see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#authenticationmanager-bean

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so in recent versions of Spring it is not enough to simply add the bean in your configurer class, you actually need to do something else.

Whatever dependency missing to autowire or to tcreate a bean, has to be specified in the main class of your application. For your case, let's say your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is under the package "configure", do the folowing:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"controller", "services", "configure"}) // This is what you need
@EntityScan("com.my.sso.server.models")
public class YourApplicationMainClass { ...
```

Also, when adding and overriding the bean, make sure @Override is above @bean:

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing class is in `spring-security-core`. Try adding this dependency:

```
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
```

Comment: Result absolutely the same

Comment: Did you refresh the Gradle project after adding the dependency?

Comment: Sure I did it. I have this class in class path but it doesn't exist in pring context

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Also very curious about that one, seems guys from spring have lack of documentation update on that one :(